# Cannot change data on DB using form in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a PHP generated HTML table that loads data from a MySQL database, in this table there is a button used to edit some information... When the button is pressed it sends the user to another page with a text field and a button.

The user can insert the new text and by pressing the button the new information should be stored in the DB, changing the old information with the new one…

But when I click the button to submit the new information, the following error appears:

> Notice: Undefined index: ident in /...patch.../upload2.php on line 11

What I'm doing wrong? (I'm new to PHP)

Here is my code:

**Resposta.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
$con=mysqli_connect(“*******”,”*******”,”*******”,”*******”);
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
  echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
    }

$emp_id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM prefeitura WHERE id = $emp_id") ;


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($row['ID']) {
echo '<p><b>ID: </b>'. $row['ID'] .'';
}   
if($row['nome']) {
echo '<p><b>SOLICITANTE: </b>'. $row['nome'] .'';
}
if($row['rua']) {
echo '<p><b>RUA: </b>'. $row['rua'] .'';
}
if($row['bairro']) {
echo '<p><b>BAIRRO: </b>'. $row['bairro'] .'</p>';
}
if($row['problema']) {
echo '<p><b>PROBLEMA: </b>'. $row['problema'] .'';
}
echo '<br>';
if($row['solucionado']) {
echo '<br><p><b>SITUAÇÃO: </b>'. $row['solucionado'] .'';
}
}
echo '<br><br><form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload2.php" method="post">';
echo '<br><input type="text" class="input-text text-area"     name="resposta" id="resposta" placeholder="Escreva a resposta" required/>';
echo '<input type="submit" class="input-btn" ident="' .$row['ID']. '"     value="Enviar Resposta" />';

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**upload2.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
$con=mysqli_connect(“*******”,”*******”,”*******”,”*******”);
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
  $emp_id = $_POST['ident'];
  $resposta = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['resposta'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); 

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE prefeitura SET solucionado = '$resposta' WHERE ID = '$emp_id';");     


header('Location: mensagem_enviada.html');
  ?>
```

Comment: Dump out your `$_POST` and see what you 've got. Need to check that `isset($_POST['ident'])`; Never trust.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the problem:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ident in /...patch.../upload2.php on line 11
```

this is telling you there is no 'ident' in $_POST variable.
Check out if 'ident' is set when you send the form.

This is yours..
`'<input type="submit" class="input-btn" ident="' .$row['ID']. '"     value="Enviar Resposta" />'`;

You should do something like this->
(edited)
    '';

You should adapt this in order to make it work. I might be missing a ' . ;

Then, another thing im seeing, you should not do this, you might be vulnerable to SQL INJECTION.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE prefeitura SET solucionado = '$resposta' WHERE ID = '$emp_id';");
```

You should use prepare statements and PDO.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I tried doing this... does not work... the ID value is not being sent

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem: the ID value was not being sent when pressing the button...

here's the piece of code that worked:

```
$mudaid = $_GET['id'];

echo <<<HTML
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload2.php" method="post">
<br><textarea rows="10" cols="70" name="resposta" id="resposta"></textarea>
<br><button type="submit" name="ident" value="$mudaid">Enviar resposta</button>
HTML;
echo '</center>';
```